# I can't sign out from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to sign out user from firebase. I'm doing just what is showed in the docs :

`fb.auth().signOut().then(res => { ...})`

It's works but when i refresh the page, the user got automatically signed in again and i can see his credentials in my `console.log`

How to persistently sign out users ?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code of your `signIn` method and the whole execution context

Comment: I just figured out that this issue totally disappear when a build my app to production. So it's nothing to do with my code but rather a problem coming from my dev environment. Maybe a caching problem